# Decode Ethereum Gas Price Golang

Tags: go-ethereum, gas, gas-price, golang

I needed to get gas data from a transaction, I did it with the code below. The received data has been converted to a string. Now I need to decode the received value. How can I do this?

````
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
)

func main() {

    dialer := websocket.DefaultDialer

    wsSubscriber, _, err := dialer.Dial("wss://api.blxrbdn.com/ws", http.Header{"Authorization": []string{"MzVkNWIzMDgtOTNhNS00MjVjLTkxN2EtZTZjOGU5N2Q3Yzk5OjFkZDhjMDZkYjk1NDcwYTQyNWI5ZmYzZTc1NDYxZWFh"}})

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    subRequest := `{"id": 1, "method": "subscribe", "params": ["newTxs", {"include": ["tx_contents"]}]}`

    err = wsSubscriber.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(subRequest))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for {
        _, nextNotification, err := wsSubscriber.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        value := gjson.Get(string(nextNotification), "params.result.txContents.gas")

        dat := value.Raw

        fmt.Println("datGas: ", dat)

        fmt.Printf("DatGas Type: %T\n", dat)```
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to decode the `gas` value. The gas value such as `"gas":"0x8caf"` is just a hexadecimal number. You are printing it out as a string. I reckon you'd like to see an actual decimal number there instead.

I recommend using the `math/big` package as numbers in ethereum can get quite big. The following code snippet converts hexadecimal strings to `big.Int` types that you can use to print out massive decimal numbers.

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    hexString1 := "0x8caf"
    hexInt1 := new(big.Int)
    hexInt1.SetString(hexString1, 0)
    fmt.Println("hexInt1:", hexInt1)

    hexString2 := "8caf"
    hexInt2 := new(big.Int)
    hexInt2.SetString(hexString2, 16)
    fmt.Println("hexInt2", hexInt2)

    hex3 := 0x8caf
    fmt.Println("hex3", hex3)
}

// Output:
//
// hexInt1: 36015
// hexInt2: 36015
// hex3: 36015
```

**To put it simply, parse `dat` variable to `big.Int` using the example above.**

**Note:** GoLang understands hexadecimal numbers, so you can also use them without quotation marks. I've added an example in the code.

Please see the online playground https://go.dev/play/p/fQjKlK-JioO

[Read more about the `big.Int` package here.](https://pkg.go.dev/math/big)